# Concurrenthashmap not getting updated between threads

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I am using a concurrent hashmap which gets populated as and when a jms message comes in. Whenever the same key comes in, it has to be overriden.

Now I am facing the problem : the map is always empty. So everytime the entry gets added instead of getting overriden.

Not sure what mistake I am doing. Kindly go through the code and help me.

```
public class Dispatcher{ 
    private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Executor> map= new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); 

    public dispatch(String key, String message) { 
    if(map.containsKey(key)){ //this always returns false. Printed to check and it is empty.
         //rest of the code 
    }else{
         map.put(key,new Executor(message)); 
         //rest of the code
    }}
public class MsgListener implements SessionAwareListener {
    Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    public void onMessage(javax.jms.Message, Session session) {
        //Rest of the code
        dispatcher.dispatch(key,msg);
}}
```

Input used for testing:

Lock1 - Message 1

Lock1 - Message 2

Lock2 - Message 3

Lock3 - Message 4

The dispatcher class gets instantiated only once inside the calling class. I have tested that and found to print the same object.

Comment: Can you share the part of the code that's supposed to add to the map?

Comment: The rest of the code would be a good idea. How do You know that the map is always empty, and not the key is different ? Are You sure you are adding the same key? Maybe try debugging? 

In case you dont know how to, at least print also the size od the map and not just contains

Comment: Added the sample input used for testing. Have used the same key as shown.

Comment: I assume that `Executor` is a class that you have defined yourself, otherwise `new Executor(message)` will fail to compile...

Comment: This may or may not be the source of your problem, but in every case it is a bug: there is a "check-then-act" race condition in your code. Instead of checking on map.contains() and then doing map.put() based on the result, use the atomic putIfAbsent method: `if (map.putIfAbsent(key, value) == null){//added}else{//not added}`

Comment: Sure.will try that. One more observation: It works perfectly with a standalone client. Not working as expected when integrating with message listener.